# How can I change the language in my LinkedIn profile?

Tags: account-management, linkedin, localization, profile

My default language on the LinkedIn website is Italian and I have compiled my job profile in both Italian and English versions. How can I set the default profile to English for the visitors?

Currently, it is not so easy to read my English profile when visiting my page because it is necessary to search a little menu for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [this FAQ entry](http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1680)

> Currently, there's no way to change the default language of your profile once you've set it up in a particular language. Many people who speak multiple languages choose to create a secondary profile for each language. Viewers will see your profile in the language most relevant to them. All language profiles will show up in search engine results on and off LinkedIn and can be accessed directly with a unique URL.
>
> You could also close your account and re-open one in your preferred language. We don't recommend this option, because you'll lose all of the connections and recommendations associated with the closed account

So you can't change it.

Comment: this is not good! It is important to show first the territorial language of the profile to international company

Answer (score 1):

> ### Choosing Which Language People View Your Profile In
>
> By default, members will see your profile in the language they’re
> using on LinkedIn. If you don’t have a profile in that language,
> they’ll see your profile in the language you used during setup.
>
> You can’t choose which language people view your profile in.
>
> However, you can **[create profiles in multiple languages](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/1717)** to
> make it easier for other members and recruiters to find you. They’ll
> have the option to manually choose the language they want to view your
> profile in from the dropdown menu on the right rail of the page.
>
> ---
>
> ### Viewing a Profile in Multiple Languages
>
> By default, you can view a profile in the language you’re using on
> LinkedIn. However, if the profile you’re viewing isn’t displayed in
> that language, you’ll see the profile in the language the member used
> during setup.
>
> You can also choose to view a profile in any language it has been
> created in. Manually select it from the dropdown menu on the right
> rail of a member’s profile page. Note: This dropdown won't be
> available if the profile was only created in one language.
>
> [image: 0]
>
> If you’re not signed in to LinkedIn, you can view a member’s public
> profile in another language by selecting it from the dropdown menu on
> the right rail of the page.
>
> [image: 0]
>
> ---
>
> ### Selecting Language Setting
>
> You can **[select your language](https://www.linkedin.com/settings/?modal=nsettings-select-language&tab=account)** from the **[Settings &
> Privacy](https://www.linkedin.com/psettings/)** page.
>
> - Click the  **Me** icon at the top of your LinkedIn homepage.
> - Click Settings & Privacy.
> - Under the **Site preferences** section of the Account tab, click **Change** next to Language.
> - Select the language you want from the dropdown.
>
> All LinkedIn-generated content, such as page titles and menus, will
> display in the language you select. Member-generated content, such as
> group discussions and recommendations, will display in the language in
> which it was written.
>
> Once you select a language, the site will remember your selection for
> subsequent visits.